# How can I make my Grafana charts start from the first of the month when I select an interval of 1M?

Tags: grafana

All my time-based Grafana charts exhibit this "issue". If I select a 1M interval, each data point (e.g. each bar in a bar chart) starts from a seemingly random day of the month, like the 10th of December in the screenshot below.

Even I set my time range to be `20xx-01-01 - 2020-12-31`.

How can I force it to show one bar per calendar month instead?

[image: chart]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that "month" is not a proper interval as it is not a constant duration. Depending on your data source, you may be able to aggregate the data by month. For example, InfluxDB 2.0 supports aggregation by month using Flux (note that prior to 2.0 aggregation by month wasn't supported).